# How fix width of table cell with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a table where one of the columns has a dynamic width. I use flex approach. But in each row, my cell has a different width. How can I fix it? Link to [example](https://jsbin.com/wimegucaso/edit?html,css,output)

"Name" column change width when I change browser window width. It works well. But other columns have the wrong width.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.t-name {
  min-width: 360px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.t-name span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="row">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th class="t-name">Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>External ID</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="t-name">T-Shirt with smile</td>
      <td>Men clothes</td>
      <td>434</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="t-name"><span>New-brand casual blue Dolche and Gabana Edt USA PRODUCTION<span></td>
      <td>Woman clothes</td>
      <td>321</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="t-name">Keds</td>
      <td>Clothes</td>
      <td>521</td>
      <td>Spring</td>
      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
```

Comment: you **never** change the display of table element, you simply break the table layout and it will become useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to maintain the `flex` declaration on your `<table>`, `<th>`, `<td>` elements, you can apply an additional `width` property to the table cells in your stylesheet, immediately beneath the `flex` declaration, like this:

```
td, th {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 90px;  // <= WIDTH DECLARATION
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
}

td, th {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 90px;
}

.t-name {
  min-width: 360px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.t-name span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="row">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th class="t-name">Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>External ID</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="t-name">T-Shirt with smile</td>
      <td>Men clothes</td>
      <td>434</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="t-name"><span>New-brand casual blue Dolche and Gabana Edt USA PRODUCTION<span></td>
      <td>Woman clothes</td>
      <td>321</td>
      <td>Summer</td>
      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="t-name">Keds</td>
      <td>Clothes</td>
      <td>521</td>
      <td>Spring</td>
      <td><button>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
```

Comment: What if my "Category" column will be long and I want to resize the column to all content but add max-width? If I add width 90px for my  "Category" column doesn't get the width for containing all content

Comment: My honest answer is that - rather than trying to combine HTML `<table>` with CSS `flex` - you really ought to be using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Here is a good game which will get you used to using all the CSS Grid Properties: [CSS Grid Garden](https://cssgridgarden.com/)